# Grails facebook graph plugin to check session in every controller

Tags: grails, facebook-graph-api, grails-plugin

I'm using grails and facebook graph plugin for the user registration. However, instead of checking facebook session in every action and controller. Is there a better way to check the session before entering controller? So, I don't have to duplicate the code to check authentication.

```
class FacebookSecurityFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                println "test"
            }
            after = {

            }
            afterView = {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created this filter by using command grails create-filters . But it's not fired at all, I mean it didn't print "test" at all. Do I need to register the filter? I'm using Grails1.4M01

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a filter - it's a great way to intercept all actions, or a subset of actions based on a pattern: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6%20Filters

Comment: I have created a file called SecurityFilters and this is the content 
class SecurityFilters {
 def filters = {
  println "test"
  loginCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {
   println "test"
   before = {
    if(!session.facebook){
     println "error From filter"
     redirect(uri:"/")
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: but it doesn't get called at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: you have blanks strings for controller and action, but they should be wildcards, e.g. `controller:'*', action:'*'` - also remove the 1st `println "test"` and move the 2nd into the `before` block

Comment: Apologies, I pasted a new code which I generated from grails command, but it's still won't fire. :(

Comment: One thing, my controllers are in a package. Does it matter? (e.g, com.mycom.LoginController)

Comment: No, controllers should be in packages, but the name you specify in the pattern is the 'logical' name, e.g. 'loginController'. But that isn't in play here since you're intercepting all. Try `grails clean` to force a full compile.